# Cómo restringir un input file para aceptar formatos de imagenes?

Tags: javascript, imagen, archivo, entrada

Buenas estoy haciendo un input file para aceptar **sólo imagenes** y pude encontrar un javascript en un foro lo cual me ha servido de ayuda, ademas de establacer en la etiqueta la propiedad accept="image/*" la cual solo ayuda al usuario a filtrar todo archivo de cualquier formato de imagenes pero de igual forma el usuario puede enviar otros formatos moviendo el selectbox de la ventana de windows, y no tendría efecto esta propiedad de la etiqueta input file mas que solo indicar al usuario que se cargan iamgenes mas no es obligatorio, por lo que no es confiable, es por eso que implemente el JS que encontre, ahora mi objetivo es que acepte imagenes de formato "**JPEG, GIF, PNG, JPG y JPE**"

La función cumple con su estandar hecho de 3 (***JPG, GIF, PNG***) formatos pero al agregar más extenciones la funcion no tiene efecto con los formatos **JPEG y JPE**

Agrego el formato JPEG con el motivo de que en algunos móviles android o tablets usan esta extención y la función al agregar 2 formatos más, declina y solo filtra **JPG,GIF y PNG**

Alguna solución o recomendación? estaba pensando hacer esto en el lado de servidor porque he visto algunas funciones con formatos mas detallados, para que las funciones no sean en lado cliente, pero sería estudiar algo más tedioso y cambiar todo lo que he hecho desde 0, agradezco la ayuda de antemano. **:D**

Dejaré todo el código:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
  #uploadForm,
  #imagePreview{
   width: 350;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }

  img{
   max-width: 350px;
   height: 0 auto;
   max-height: 300px;
  }
 </style>
       
       <div class="col-sm-12">

       <div class="col-sm-12" id="imagePreview">
        
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="background-color: #c8dadf;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 50px;padding-bottom: 50px">
         <br>            
         <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p style="text-align: center;"><b>Cargar Foto</b></p>      
          <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imagedoc" name="imagedoc" accept="image/*" onBlur='LimitAttach(this,1);'>          
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
        
       </div>

       <input id="btn_Agregar_Usuario" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Terminar" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 (function(){
  function filePreview(input){
   if (input.files && input.files[0]){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e){
     $('#imagePreview').html("<img src='"+e.target.result+"' />");
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
  }

  $('#imagedoc').change(function(){
   filePreview(this);
  });
 })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function LimitAttach(tField,iType) {
  file=tField.value;
  if (iType==1) {
  extArray = new Array(".jpeg",".jpe",".gif",".jpg",".png");
  } 
  allowSubmit = false;
  if (!file) return;
  while (file.indexOf("\\") != -1) file = file.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
  ext = file.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {
  if (extArray[i] == ext) {
  allowSubmit = true;
  break;
  }
  }
  if (allowSubmit) {
  } else {
  tField.value="";
  alert("Usted sólo puede subir archivos con extensiones " + (extArray.join(" ")) + "\n Reiniciando Formulario");
  setTimeout("location.reload()",2000);
  }
  } 
</script>
```

Donde  el **JavaScript de LimitarExtenciones** es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LimitAttach(tField,iType) {
    file=tField.value;
    if (iType==1) {
    extArray = new Array(".gif",".jpg",".png"); /*AQUI AGREGUÉ LAS 2 EXTENSIONES SIN OBTENER RESULTADOS POSITIVOS (".jpeg",".jpe",)*/
    }   
    allowSubmit = false;
    if (!file) return;
    while (file.indexOf("\\") != -1) file = file.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
    ext = file.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {
    if (extArray[i] == ext) {
    allowSubmit = true;
    break;
    }
    }
    if (allowSubmit) {
    } else {
    tField.value="";
    alert("Usted sólo puede subir archivos con extensiones " + (extArray.join(" ")) + "\n Reiniciando Formulario");
    setTimeout("location.reload()",2000);
    }
    }</script>
```

Comment: Esto debería poder solucionar a tu necesidad: [Allow only pdf, doc, docx format for file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992586/allow-only-pdf-doc-docx-format-for-file-upload)

Answer (score 3):

El error pasa básicamente porque no realizas la validación al cambiar el input. Prueba añadiendo validación con esto:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style media="screen">
  #uploadForm,
  #imagePreview {
    width: 350;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  img {
    max-width: 350px;
    height: 0 auto;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
</style>

<div class="col-sm-12">

  <div class="col-sm-12" id="imagePreview">

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group" style="background-color: #c8dadf;border-radius: 5px;padding-left: 50px;padding-bottom: 50px">
      <br>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p style="text-align: center;"><b>Cargar Foto</b></p>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imagedoc" name="imagedoc" accept="image/*">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<input id="btn_Agregar_Usuario" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Terminar" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    function filePreview(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#imagePreview').html("<img src='" + e.target.result + "' />");
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }

    $('#imagedoc').change(function(el) {
      if (LimitAttach(this, 1))
        filePreview(this);
    });
  })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function LimitAttach(tField, iType) {
    file = tField.value;
    if (iType == 1) {
      extArray = new Array(".jpeg", ".jpe", ".gif", ".jpg", ".png");
    }
    allowSubmit = false;
    if (!file) return false;
    while (file.indexOf("\\") != -1) file = file.slice(file.indexOf("\\") + 1);
    ext = file.slice(file.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < extArray.length; i++) {
      if (extArray[i] == ext) {
        allowSubmit = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (allowSubmit) {
      return true
    } else {
      tField.value = "";
      alert("Usted sólo puede subir archivos con extensiones " + (extArray.join(" ")) + "\n Reiniciando Formulario");
      return false;
      setTimeout("location.reload()", 2000);
    }
  }
</script>
```

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para validar las extensiones y peso de los archivos cargados mediante un input type="file" yo implemento el siguiente código:

```
<input type="file" name="text1" id="text1" Class="FormField" onchange="validarFile(this);">

<script>
//Funcion de JS que valida el archivo ingresado al input. Formato y Tamaño.
function validarFile(all)
{
    //EXTENSIONES Y TAMANO PERMITIDO.
    var extensiones_permitidas = [".png", ".bmp", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx", ".gif"];
    var tamano = 8; // EXPRESADO EN MB.
    var rutayarchivo = all.value;
    var ultimo_punto = all.value.lastIndexOf(".");
    var extension = rutayarchivo.slice(ultimo_punto, rutayarchivo.length);
    if(extensiones_permitidas.indexOf(extension) == -1)
    {
        alert("Extensión de archivo no valida");
        document.getElementById(all.id).value = "";
        return; // Si la extension es no válida ya no chequeo lo de abajo.
    }
    if((all.files[0].size / 1048576) > tamano)
    {
        alert("El archivo no puede superar los "+tamano+"MB");
        document.getElementById(all.id).value = "";
        return;
    }
}
</script>
```

Del lado del servidor, también realizo las mismas validaciones, pero en PHP obviamente. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

### Ejemplo para hacer lo que pides

> Esta es la parte de html y javascript

```html
  <form class="col-md-12" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label style="cursor:pointer" for="file-upload" class="form-control" id="label_custom">Elegir archivos</label>
            <input class="" id="file-upload" onchange="cambiar()" style="display: none" type="file" name="archivo[]" value="" multiple="multiple">
            <input class="button-blue btnn" type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir">
            <p id="info"></p>

        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function cambiar(){
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = ""; //borramos el contenido del parrafo info cada vez q se eligen los nuevvos archivos para subir
            var cambio = document.getElementById('file-upload').files;
            for(var i=0; i < cambio.length; i++){
              document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += cambio[i].name+"</br>";
            }
          }
          if(document.getElementById('file-upload').files > 0){
            cambiar();
          }

      </script>
```

> Esta es la parte de php que se encarga de comprobar

```
    <?php
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '50M');

    if (isset($_FILES['archivo']) && ($_FILES['archivo']) > 0 ) {

      foreach ($_FILES["archivo"]["name"] as $key => $error) {         
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]);
        $temp = $pathinfo['extension'];
        if($temp != "gif" && $temp != "png" && $temp != "jpeg" && $temp != "jpg"){
          $name = basename($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]);
          echo "<p style='padding-left:10px;color:#E53C2B'>".$name." - No valido</p>";
        }else{
          $tmp_name = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key];
          $name = basename($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]);
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/".$name);
          echo "<p style='padding-left:10px;color:#58E52B'>".$name." ✔</p>";
        }
     }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una descripción de lo que hacen o cómo solucionan el problema se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles. Lee [answer] para más información.