# Como permitir la carga de archivos con formato PDF o jpg

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy presentando un inconveniente al momento de querer cargar archivos en `asp.NET` con un cierto formato, solamente deseo cargar archivos de tipo PDF y jpg.

La siguiente es la vista con la cual cargo los documentos

```
<body class="bodydoc">
    <div class="documento">
        @if (@Model.FileType ==
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        || Convert.ToSingle(Model.FileContentSize) > 1500

    )
        else
        {
            
        <object data="data:@Model.FileType;base64,@Model.FileContent"
                width="550px" height="400px"></object>
        }
        
    </div>
</body>
```

El siguiente es la clase con la que cargo los documentos:

```
public class FileInfoFtp
    {
        public FileInfoFtp()
        {
        }
        public string FileName { get; internal set; }
        public string FileType { get; internal set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string FileId { get; }

        private string fileContent;

        public string FileContentSize { get; internal set; }
        public string FileContent
        {
            get => fileContent;
            set
            {
                fileContent = value;
                this.FileContentSize = (value.Length / 1000).ToString("#0,00");
            }
        }
    }
```

El problema que estoy presentando es que me esta permitiendo la carga de cualquier tipo de archivos desde un `.exe` hasta un archivo `.sql`, quisiera limitar a solo los archivos que mencione anteriormente.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

El siguiente es el código de la ventana en la cual cargo el archivo

```
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 1rem 1rem;background-color: #f7f7f7">

                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;justify-content: center; padding-top: 1rem; padding-top: 1rem;padding-left: 2rem;">
                                <img style="width:50%" src="~/images/Recursos/image6.png" class="img-responsive" />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content: space-around;">
                                        <label type="text" id="clave" name="clave" style="display:none;"></label>
                                        <div style="margin-right: 20px;" onclick="borrar()">
                                            <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                                                <img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image5.png" />
                                            </label>
                                            @*<button id="uploadBtn" style="background-image:url(../images/Recursos/image5.png)"></button>*@
                                            <input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <label>
                                                <img onclick="guardar()" id="SubirArchivo" style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image4.png" />
                                            </label>
                                            @*<input  type="file" style="display:none;">*@
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div style="text-align:center">
                                        <label id="fileName" style="color:#a1a0a1;font-family:'Montserrat-Bold'"></label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="alert alert-warning" id="notFound" style="display:none">
                                        <strong id="textoAdvertencia"></strong>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalExito">

                <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 1rem 1rem;background-color: #f7f7f7">

                        <div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>

                                    <div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-around;">
                                        <img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image2.png" />
                                    </div>

                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-around;" onclick="refrescar()">
                                        <label data-dismiss="modal" style="cursor:pointer"><img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image3.png" /></label>
                                        @*<img style="width:225px;align-content:center" src="~/images/Recursos/image3.png" />*@
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalError">

                <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 1rem 1rem;background-color: #f7f7f7">
                        <div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-around;">
                                        <img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image.png" />
                                    </div>

                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <div style="display:flex;justify-content: space-around;">
                                        <label data-dismiss="modal" style="cursor:pointer"><img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image1.png" /></label>

                                        @*<img style="width:225px;align-content:center" src="~/images/Recursos/image3.png" />*@
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalPrueba">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div id="progressOuter" class="progress progress-striped active hidden">
                                <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                    <!– Botón para adjuntar archivos –>
                                    <button id="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Examinar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <!– div para mensajes de error y otros mensajes deseados –>
                                    <div id="msgBox" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-success"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="ModalImagen">

                <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="padding: 1rem 1rem;background-color: #f7f7f7">

                        <div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="modal-body">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="mi-modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <label style="font-family:'Montserrat-Bold'">¿Acepta continuar con la carga del archivo?</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="modal-btn-si">Si</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-btn-no">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:**

Probando una de las respuestas de Angel Reyna lo adapte al código mío para al momento de cargar un archivo diferente a un PDF no me sale la excepción de `Extensión no permitida`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#file-upload').change(function () {
        var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop();
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            if (ext == "pdf") {
                alert("La extensión es: " + ext);
                $('#ModalError').modal('hide');
                var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
                var file = $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name;
                document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = file;
            } else {
                $("#modal-gral").hide();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
            alert("Extensión no permitida: " + ext);
        }
    
});
```

Saben si estoy haciendo algo mal con el manejo de excepciones

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 3:**

Agrego la función completa del método de carga, pero aquí sigo con el problema de excepción cuando no es un archivo PDF.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#file-upload').change(function () {
        var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop();
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            if (ext == "pdf") {
                alert("La extensión es: " + ext);
                $('#ModalError').modal('hide');
                var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
                var file = $('#file-upload')[0].files[0].name;
                document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = file;
            } else {
                $("#modal-gral").hide();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).val('');
            alert("Extensión no permitida: " + ext);
        }

        $('#myModalCarga').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            //debugger;
            document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = "";
            $('#file-upload').val('')
            $('#notFound').css("display", "none");
            //window.location.reload();
        });

        var docsalumn;
        ObtenerDocumentos();

        $('#trigger').click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        });
        $('#top').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'right': '30px',
            'bottom': '30px',
        });
        $("#return").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "right": "30px",
            "top": "30px",
        }).on("click", function () {
            window.history.back();
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Hola Sebastian, entendi el codigo .net pero mi duda es del lado del lado HTML / javascritpt ... necesitas subir archivos desde la web via ajax al servidor controlando el mime type?

Comment: @toto No utilizo ningún código javascript para validar el formato de los archivos que se suben

Comment: Puedes utilizar un atributo, donde controles las extensiones permitidas, igualmente puede controlar el mimetype desde javascript.

Comment: @Jairo1010 Puedes agregar un ejemplo como respuesta para validarla como correcta por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes permitido dejar que elija el archivo y luego validar la extención con jquery puedes hacerlo de esta manera que incluye el peso:
codigo [de](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191833/c%C3%B3mo-validar-solo-pdf-en-input-file) [Cómo validar solo PDF en Input File](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191833/c%C3%B3mo-validar-solo-pdf-en-input-file)

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
  var ext = $( this ).val().split('.').pop();
  if ($( this ).val() != '') {
    if(ext == "pdf"){
      alert("La extensión es: " + ext);
      if($(this)[0].files[0].size > 1048576){
        console.log("El documento excede el tamaño máximo");
        $('#modal-title').text('¡Precaución!');
        $('#modal-msg').html("Se solicita un archivo no mayor a 1MB. Por favor verifica.");
        $("#modal-gral").modal();           
        $(this).val('');
      }else{
        $("#modal-gral").hide();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $( this ).val('');
      alert("Extensión no permitida: " + ext);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" />
```

En la tercer actualizacion veo que retiraste el if del tamaño pero no el else, dejo una extraccion de tu codigo y como deberia estar el jqueri si retiras la validación del tamaño

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                                                
 <img style="width:225px" src="~/images/Recursos/image5.png" />
                                       
 </label>
                                        
@*<button id="uploadBtn" style="background-image:url(../images/Recursos/image5.png)"></button>*@
                                        
<input id="file-upload" name='upload_cont_img' type="file" style="display:none;">
                                
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#file-upload').on('change', 
function(){
  var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop();
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    if(ext == "pdf"){
      alert("La extensión es: " + ext);
    }
    else
    {
      $( this ).val('');
      alert("Extensión no permitida: " + ext);
    }
  }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, revisa mi ultima actualización estoy presentando un problema con la excepción.

Comment: Con que boton estas abriendo el buscador de windows? Con una vista rapida veo que el que tiene id file-upload esta oculto con display:none y luego hay un boton de examinar

Comment: Así es, en una de mis actualizaciones esta la vista, primero se abre una ventana modal para examinar la carpeta, luego va y busca en Windows, despues se cierra y aparece el nombre del archivo que se cargo debajo de los botones, y por ultimo se presiona subir archivo y sale el mensaje de confirmación

Comment: @Sebastian Salazar ahora que veo el jquery que usas agregaste el document.ready, segun veo no cierras el corchete y parentesis de la funcion, la ultima linea sería algo como });})  prueba de esa forma

Comment: Intente lo de agregar el corchete y el paréntesis pero sigo con el mismo problema de la excepción, revisa la ultima actualización agregue toda la función completa para la carga del archivo.

Comment: Ví que retiraste el if de la validacion del tamaño pero no su else, edité la respuesta con un pequeño ejemplo sin la validación del tamaño.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección ya me funciona la validación cuando no es un archivo PDF, pero en este caso necesito que permita PDF y JPG como agrego la segunda validación de archivos JPG ?

Comment: para permitir mas extenciones lo puedes agregar en el if con un Or ( || ), así: if(ext == "pdf" || ext == "jpg") . Considera que tambien hay jpeg, recuerda que tambien te podrías encontrar mayusculas y minusculas, para considerarlo puedes agregar uno por uno o de manera insensitiva los que coinciden letras

Answer (score 0):

En tu input type ="file" deberás indicarle mediante el método accept que solo te admita archivos pdf y jpeg

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf,image/jpeg">
```